# Program in Python doesn't match equal words

Tags: python, n-gram, utf8-decode

I have a list of some 4-grams that I want to find in a text, but I'm having trouble with some words with accents.
For example, lets say our 4-gram list is 
`Quad = [(u'Jogos', u'Olímpicos', u'de', u'Verão'), (u'Jogos', u'Olímpicos', u'de', u'Inverno'), (u'Jogos', u'Olímpicos', u'de', u'Sidney')]`

I have a small txt for test that this:

```
'Tasha fez parte da equipe norte americana que disputou os Jogos Olímpicos de Sidney em 2000 na Austrália'
```

But I'm unable to match that 'Jogos Olímpicos de Sidney' from the text with the one on my 4-gram.

I tried a couple of things,

First:
I made a second list `Quad2 = [u'Jogos_Ol\xedmpicos_de_Ver\xe3o', u'Jogos_Ol\xedmpicos_de_Inverno', u'Jogos_Ol\xedmpicos_de_Sidney']`

That's the output, if I do Quad2[2] I get Jogos_Olímpicos_de_Sidney

When I try

```
while i < (len(test) - 3):
if (test[i] + '_' + test[i+1] + '_' + test[i+2] + '_' + test[i+3]) in Quad2:
print test[i]
```

It doesn't print anything.

Second:

```
while k< len(test)-3:
    for i in range(3):
        if test[k] == Quad[i][0] and test[k+1] == Quad[i][1] and test[k+2] == Quad[i][2] and test[k+3] == Quad[i][3]:
            print test[k]
    k = k+1
```

With words without accents both methods words, but it words like 'Olímpicos' it does't. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is your test text quoted with a u for unicode?

Comment: You've got 3 different spellings of "test" btw ("tes", "test", "teste")

Comment: No, I just saved that sentence in a test.txt, and I opened like this: data = "/home/portugues/teste.txt"
f = open(data)
f.seek(0)
test = f.read().split(' ')

Comment: Make sure you open the file as unicode. Read this: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Sorry, the original name was 'teste' and I wanted to change to 'test' here. It worked! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Cool. Could you accept my answer below so we know it's done? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open your test file to read it as Unicode:

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('/home/portugues/teste.txt', encoding='utf-8')
test = f.read().split(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem with the accents as far as I see it. Python has methods for joining strings and for finding a substring from a string. It would be better to use those if possible.

```
test = u'Tasha fez parte da equipe norte americana que disputou os Jogos Olímpicos de Sidney em 2000 na Austráli'

quads = [(u'Jogos', u'Olímpicos', u'de', u'Verão'),
         (u'Jogos', u'Olímpicos', u'de', u'Inverno'),
         (u'Jogos', u'Olímpicos', u'de', u'Sidney')]

for quad in quads:
    x = u' '.join(quad)
    res = test.find(x)
    if res >= 0:
        print("Found:", test[res:res+len(x)])
```